# Split geom_point points along x axis by group

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is driving me up the wall, and I'm sure I am missing something simple. Any help would be appreciated.

I want the red and blue points to be separated, with each set over the corresponding boxplot as in second image, but with a numeric x axis as in the first image.

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(c(1, 2, 10), each = 20), 
               g = rep(c("A", "B"), times = 30), 
               y = c(rnorm(60, 0, 1)))

# OK - boxplot by x and g
  ggplot(df, aes(y = y, x = x, fill = g, color = g, group = interaction(x, g))) +
    geom_boxplot() 

# Not OK. The dots are only grouped by x, not g  
  ggplot(df, aes(y = y, x = x, fill = g, color = g, group = interaction(x, g))) +
    geom_point() 

# I want the points to correctly overlay the boxplots
  ggplot(df, aes(y = y, x = x, fill = g, color = g, group = interaction(x, g))) +
    geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.1) +
    geom_point()
```

[image]

(I have fixed it by faceting on x, but I want the axis as numeric to reflect the correct scaling)

```
   ggplot(df, aes(y = y, x = g, fill = g, color = g, group = interaction(x, g))) +
     geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.1) +
     geom_point() +
     facet_wrap(~x)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want the red and blue points to be separated, each overlayed over the boxplot as in second image but with a numeric x axis as in the first image?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `position=position_dodge(...)` in `geom_point`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(y = y, x = x, fill = g, color = g, group = interaction(x, g))) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.1, width=0.75) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width=0.75))
```

I also defined a width for `geom_boxplot` to match the `position_dodge` width in `geom_point`.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

In case you want jitter as well, you can use `position_jitterdodge`.

```
 ggplot(df, aes(y = y, x = x, fill = g, color = g, group = interaction(x, g))) +
       geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.1, width=0.75) +
       geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width=0.85))
```

Comment: Also a fan of `position_jitterdodge`. I would suggest a `jitter.width=0.6` or value less than the `geom_boxplot` width so the points do not travel past the boundaries of the matching boxplot.

Answer (score 2):

If using `geom_beeswarm`, you can use the `dodge.width` option

```
 library(ggbeeswarm)

 ggplot(df, aes(y = y, x = x, fill = g, color = g, group = interaction(x, g))) +
    geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.1, width = 0.75) +
    geom_beeswarm(dodge.width = 0.75)
```

[image]